# VBA - Get the Second-Last modified file (FSO) without built-in functions

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get the one Before the Last modified File in a Folder Using Excel VBA, I have managed to Get the Last Modified File, But I couldn't get the second one.
Herein Below the code I used to get the Last Modified File, without using system Functions or built-in function.

```
Sub LastFileModified()

    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fill As Scripting.File


    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ForStep As Integer

    Dim Arr() As Variant

    ReDim Arr(fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Shahim\Desktop\xxxx").Files.Count - 1, 1) As Variant

  i = 0

For Each fill In fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Shahim\Desktop\xxxx").Files

    Arr(i, 0) = fill.Name
    Arr(i, 1) = CDbl(fill.DateLastModified)

    i = i + 1

Next fill


Dim filename As String
Dim Initializer As Double

Initializer = Arr(0, 1)

For ForStep = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)


        If Arr(ForStep, 1) > Initializer Then

        Initializer = Arr(ForStep, 1)
        filename = Arr(ForStep, 0)

        End If



Next ForStep

Debug.Print filename

Erase Arr

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub SecodLastModified()

    Const FLDR_PATH As String = "C:\Test"

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, fileArr() As String, maxFiles As Long
    Dim fso As Variant, fldr As Variant, f As Variant, l1 As String, l2 As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(FLDR_PATH)
    maxFiles = fldr.Files.Count
    ReDim fileArr(1 To maxFiles, 1 To 2)

    i = 1
    For Each f In fldr.Files
        fileArr(i, 1) = f.Name
        fileArr(i, 2) = f.DateLastModified
        i = i + 1
    Next
    For i = 1 To maxFiles
        For j = i + 1 To maxFiles
            If fileArr(j, 2) > fileArr(i, 2) Then
                l1 = fileArr(i, 2)
                l2 = fileArr(i, 1)
                fileArr(i, 2) = fileArr(j, 2)
                fileArr(i, 1) = fileArr(j, 1)
                fileArr(j, 2) = l1
                fileArr(j, 1) = l2
            End If
        Next
    Next
    MsgBox fileArr(2, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: This is fine, but the point here that I don't want to use methods like Sort or Max, see when I get the Last Modified File, there I could use the Max Function instead.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The original answer did not work for me for two reasons.

1. fileArr(i,2) was not declared a date, and occassionally Excel could not decipher what was the greater date. When I tried to dim this as a date, it said I could not dim an Array.
2. If temporary files were included, it did not skip over those files.

Here is what worked for me.

```
Function SecodLastModified(Directory)

Dim FileSys As FileSystemObject
Dim objFile As File, objFile1 As File
Dim myFolder
Dim strFilename As String, strFolder As String, myDir As String
Dim strFilenameFirst As String, strFilenameSecond As String, strFilenameSecond1 As String
Dim dteFile As Date, dteFileSecond1 As Date, dteFileFirst As Date, dteFileSecond As Date
Dim openLastFile

'set up filesys objects
Set FileSys = New FileSystemObject
Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(Directory)

dteFileSecond1 = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
'loop through each file and get date last modified. If largest date then store Filename
For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
    For Each objFile1 In myFolder.Files
        ' To prevent opening temporary files
        If objFile1.Name Like "*.xlsx" And Left(objFile1.Name, 2) <> "~$" Then
            If objFile1.DateLastModified > objFile.DateLastModified Then
                dteFileSecond = objFile.DateLastModified
                strFilenameSecond = objFile.Name
                dteFileFirst = objFile1.DateLastModified
                strFilenameFirst = objFile1.Name
                ' If second file date is greater than current second file, store away as the second file
                If dteFileSecond > dteFileSecond1 Then
                    dteFileSecond1 = objFile.DateLastModified
                    strFilenameSecond1 = objFile.Name
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next objFile

Set SecodLastModified = Workbooks.Open(Directory & "\" & strFilenameSecond1)
Set FileSys = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
End Function
```